# Branches other than master are hidden after cloning a Git repo?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

When I do a `git clone` and then a `git branch`, only the `master` shows up. I only see the other branches from the remote when I do `git branch -a`.

Why are the other branches hidden?

Comment: Also, I think this duplicate would be worth keeping around (i.e. don't delete it please), because it uses different keywords and phrasing from the canonical question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did a normal clone and didn't use `--depth=1`, they're not hidden, you just haven't made a local copy yet. To check out one of the other branches, just run:

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

It'll detect the remote branch and check out that version of the code locally.